# More varied/unique sponsored icons

Tags: discussion, advertising, user-interface, sponsored-tags

The sponsored icons is a nice concept.. From my view the "sponsoring" part is irrelevant, but the "icon" part is not - it makes the tags quickly identifiable at a glance.. No more reading a bunch of identical looking tags, there's nice unique, colourful icons next to them!

[Screenshot of question with adobe sponsored tags http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/6715/adobetechicon.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/6715/adobetechicon.png)

This makes it obvious the question is about Adobe-related technology. The problem is when multiple Adobe related tags are used:

[Screenshot of question with multiple Adobe sponsored tags http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7615/clutteredicons.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7615/clutteredicons.png)

That's just.. cluttered. Couldn't the Flex icon be shown next to the flex tag? Couldn't the Flash icon be shown next to the `flash` tag?

[Mockup of question with unique icons http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8523/uniqueicons.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8523/uniqueicons.png)

Comment: Your post is getting lost in the images.

Comment: @Smithers That does help a little.

Comment: It's always a pleasure to help you, random :)

Comment: Needs freehand circles.

Answer (score 8):

I like this idea myself, but I think ultimately it would be up to the sponsor how they decide to "iconify" tags. I mean, if Adobe wanted I'm sure they could have multiple icons (although honestly they wouldn't have the immediate visual effectiveness as the Adobe logo itself).

Comment: That's basically what it comes down to. We suggested the approach above, but they prefered to go with their logo instead. Obviously, we won't let someone put just *anything* (say... ponies) on the tag, but a company logo seemeded perfectly reasonable

Comment: @Alex: If I gave you $5 would you allow the "ponies" tag to have a picture of a pony on it?

Comment: @Alex: I will give you $6 if you put an image that says "TheTXI smells" on the "ponies" tag instead.

Comment: @Alex: I will give you $7 if you put an image that says "I Gave $7 To Get Here" on the "ponies" tag instead.

Comment: @Alex: In response to TheTXI's latest proposal, I am upping my offer to $7 and a TDWTF sticker (valued at $100).

Comment: @Alex: I counter with $3.50 and the head of Rich B on a paper picnic plate.

Comment: @TheTXI: Sorry, Alex has already slain Rich once.  He doesn't need your help.

Comment: You can never have too many Rich B heads hanging from your walls. And we all know once you cut one off, two more just grow back anyway.

Comment: But back to our serious discussion...Do you have a counter proposal?

Comment: @TheTXI: Of course I do: $7, the TDWTF sticker, a framed photo of Welbog poorly photoshopped as a member of the Jackson 5, and a subscription to **Stormwater Magazine**, which bills itself as the leading publication among surface water quality professionals throughout North America.

Comment: @Pesto: How about $7, two envelopes full of Trilogy stickers, three lunch buffet coupons for Pizza Hut, a yellow trucker hat, and a broken mug?

Comment: @TheTXI: $7, the sticker, Welbog Jackson, Stormwater Magazine, an unopened Linksys LNE100TX Ethernet card, and the little metal 'O' that fell off my Oakley sunglasses.

Comment: @Pesto: $8. See if you can beat that.

Comment: @TheTXI: Since the TDWTF sticker is a $100 value, I think I already did.  But, if Alex acts now, I'll throw in a can of Diet Mtn Dew UltraViolet, which is mixed-berry flavored and not entirely awful.

Comment: @Pesto: I would have to ask to have that TDWTF sticker appraised. I don't believe that anything that close to Washington D.C. can maintain its value for that long.

Comment: @TheTXI: Since Alex has an avatar very similar to the thedailywtf.com logo (and the sticker), I bet he'd really appreciate it.  Thus it's a $100 value to him.  Any appraiser worth his salt (as determined by an appraiser of appraisers) would tell you that.

Comment: @Pesto: You know what, screw the sticker and toss in a screenshot of our previous discussion of SOLID, LIQUID, and GAS Principles instead.

Comment: @TheTXI: I'll do you one better: a screenshot of that discussion with freehand circles!

Comment: @Pesto: Oh god, don't get me too worked up now.

Answer (score 7):

***O.M.G. Ponies!!!***

[TheTXI http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-omg-ponies.png](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-omg-ponies.png)

Comment: Hijacking my meme to beat me in votes. Well played Sir.

Comment: @TheTXI: go ahead and make the `[waffles]` tag :)